# Get file contents when Connection is keep-alive

Tags: php

I need to get the contents of a remote file, but with sending a few headers, and one of them is the "Connection: keep-alive" header... so I tried it with a simple call to file_get_contents(), like this:

```
<?php

$sfheaders="Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive";

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => $sfheaders
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$url="http://somedomain.com/to.php";
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

... the code works, but it takes 15 seconds for file_get_contents to get the data! It looks like file_get_contents() finishes after the connection closes, but I want it to finish after the data is transferred. It is faster if I remove the keep-alive header but this time I need to get the data while the connection is kept alive.  I guess that is not possible with file_get_contents, so ....

is there a way to do it with cURL or with something else?

Edit: Let me be more accurate, the "Connection:keep-alive" header must be send to the specific server I am trying to access because it checks for that header, and if it is not send, then there is no data send to me! Got it?

Comment: That the server won't send data if your app does not send keep-alive, is quite unlikely. Are your absolutely sure?

Comment: yup, it is not my server, but I am sure ;) I know it is unusual :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Keep-alive connections**

Normally, if a connection isn't set as `keep-alive`, once PHP terminates the current script, the remaining output buffer gets forwarded to the web-server, which in turn forwards the data to the client. Then the web-server **closes its connection** to the client (browser).

If you request

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

the server does just this: It **keeps the connection open**, even if a reply has completely finished. Thus, the mentioned behavior is just fine. **Furthermore, e.g. `feof()` won't return FALSE - since more data might arrive eventually.**

Note, that you can re-use the keep-alive connection within your currently running PHP script. But once your PHP script finishes, the keep-alive connection will be disconnected.

Thus, you **can't reuse** the keep-alive connection using your next PHP script instance.

**Case 1 - Amount of data known before request**

If you know the amount of data beforehand, you might read just that amount of data `$expectedAmountOfDataInBytes` and then close the connection:

```
$expectedAmountOfDataInBytes = 2023;

$handle = fopen( "http://www.stackoverflow.com/", "r" );

if ( ! is_resource( $handle )) {
    echo 'sorry';
    exit;
}

while(  ( ! feof( $handle ) )
     && ( 0 < $expectedAmountOfDataInBytes-- )
     ) {

    $contents .= fread( $handle, 1 );

}

fclose($handle);
```

**Case 2 - Amount of data unknown before request**

In case you don't know the amount of data beforehand, you need to submit a [HTTP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request

```
GET /infotext.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.net
```

and parse an answer like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/1.3.29 (Unix) PHP/4.3.4
Content-Length: 4 
Content-Language: de (nach RFC 3282 sowie RFC 1766)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

ABCD
```

Find in the [PHP Manuals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) a simple HTTP client based on [sockets I/O](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).

Comment: And here I have another problem, the amount of data is unknown, that is it changes from time to time ;) ... I already tryed something like this, but only with _while(!feof($handle))_, and that took the same as file_get_contents... hmm, I guess I will try to find the size for this, maybe by checking the headers,  but yes that should work... thanks for the reply

Comment: @EdisGolubić I enhanced my answer and provided a starting point. Have a look.